# Difference between instance variable and local variable when passing a field to super constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

Custom Text: 1

```
class FooText extends Text {
  final String data; // Instance variable
  FooText(this.data) : super(data.toUpperCase());
}
```

Custom Text: 2

```
class BarText extends Text {
  BarText(String data) : super(data.toUpperCase()); // Local variable
}
```

Here's how I use them:

```
FooText('hello') // prints 'hello' (bad)
BarText('hello') // prints 'HELLO' (good)
```

As you can see when I use local variable, the call to super works as expected but when I use instance variable it doesn't. So, what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart doesn't need the keyword `@override` anymore, so your `data` variable inside `FooText` is overriding the super variable since it seems to be matching the name. The instance will access the overrided variable.

Comment: That's what I said. The override keyword is not required and the {data} variable has been replaced. Because the variable of the super has been replaced by the {data} from the sub class, the returned value is the one coming from the sub class.